# B flat in B flat major scale

Tags: piano, sheet-music, key-signatures, accidentals

I was looking at playing [Megalovania](https://www.ninsheetmusic.org/download/pdf/2689) and came across a B flat on measure 41. Normally, I would play a B flat, but since it it is already a B flat from the B flat major chord, I am super confused. Is this a typo from whoever wrote the music, or does something weird happen with the note? I assume it either cancels out or becomes an A, but then wouldn't they just have wrote it as an A or with a natural? How should I play that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a [courtesy accidental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)#Courtesy_accidentals). Look at the measure before:

[image: measure 40]

The B-flats are naturalised there. But they have to be flat again in measure 41:

[image: measure 41]

The extra flat in measure 41 is to remind the player that the B's are flat again. So you just play a B-flat there. Successive identical accidentals are never added together, a B-double flat would be depicted with two b's before the same note.